# Samsung S-Pen Touchscreen Sampling Frequency

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm developing a drawing analysis application for the Galaxy Note 10.1 2014, and I need a very high level of precision to have a precise level of analysis.
When I'm not using the SCanvasView to draw the traces, I get about 60 events a second (60Hz). However, when I'm using the SCanvasView to draw, I only get between 15 and 20 events per second, which is fairly low.

I be wrong, but my understanding of the way events work is that the scheduler fires an event whenever the UI thread is ready to receive them. Which means that the reason why the frequency would be so low when using the SCanvasView would be that the beautification of the trace and what not takes too much juice, leaving the UI thread with only enough juice to work at 20Hz.

The other fairly strong possibility is that the SCanvasView somehow throttles the SPenTouchListener at 20Hz when drawing is going on. I say that it looks like a fairly storng possibility because the frequency remains pretty steadily at 20Hz, without ever going over. Not ever going to 21Hz for exemple seems a bit suspicious to me.
If the SCanvasView drawing funcitonality indeed throttles the move touch event frequency, is there any way to disable or go around that throttling?

If, on the other hand, it's only the drawing functionality that's slowing the UI thread down, is there a way to use a second thread to make the beautification calculations and only post the bitmap modifications on the UI thread, freeing some time on the UI thread?

And, lastly, if the SCanvasView actually reads more than 20 points per second but only exposes 20 events per second, is there any way to read these dots directly?